# How do I dynamically retrieve data from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

New to flutter & firebase. I am trying to retrieve user data from Firebase with the help of a stream and then trying to display it for the user in the Stream Builder widget. This is code for retrieval

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  CollectionReference vaccTaken = Firestore.instance.collection('User');



  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return vaccTaken.document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered').document().snapshots()
      .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.data['name'],
      vaccineName: snapshot.data['vaccine given'],
    );
  }
```

and this for displaying the retrieved data

```
class _VaccBodyState extends State<VaccBody> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index){
                  return new Text(snapshot.data[index]);
                }
              ))
            ],
          )
        );
        }else{
        return Container(
          child: Text('No data')
        );
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Even if there is data in the firebase, the else part of condition is being shown i.e no data is being shown. I have no idea where I am going wrong.
The documents im trying to retrieve are in the folder User/uid/VaccineAdministered.

Database:

[image]

Comment: add a screenshot of ur firestore

Comment: @peter uploaded! https://imgur.com/qXz0Zps

Comment: inside`_userDataFromSnapshot` do print(snapshot.data) and check what do u get

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return vaccTaken.document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered').document().snapshots()
```

into this:

```
return vaccTaken.document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered').snapshots()
```

You need to reference the document when retrieving the data

Comment: thank for the reply, but woudnt it only return that specific document? i want to retrieve all the documents in the 'Vaccine Administered' folder!

Comment: can u try `return vaccTaken.document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered').snapshots()` , also what did the print give you?

Comment: ```return vaccTaken.document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered').snapshots()```
is giving me an error 
```lib/services/database.dart:39:12: Error: The argument type 'UserDataFunction(DocumentSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 
'UserData Function(QuerySnapshot)'.
```


and the print(snapshot.data) is returning null!

Comment: here's the code just in case https://github.com/arpit-d/hospital_app  
the retrieval code is in services/database.dart and the display code is in screens/home/vacc_reminder.dart

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that error, you need to check your code. But in the documentation it says you can call snapahots() on collections() https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: just to make sure, this is where i was supposed to use the print function, right? https://imgur.com/a/Ney4ftg

Comment: Yes you can write it under here also `(context,snapshot) { print(snapshot) `

Comment: same result! so basically its not able to find the documents in firebase right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209330/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-arpit).